# Cant Post JSON Object using Jquery.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have the following object that gets created in my javascript application.

```
    poll_data[active_question] = {
        'question': $('div.question_wrap textarea').attr('value'),
        'answers':  [
            $('div.answer_wrap input#0').attr('value'),
            $('div.answer_wrap input#1').attr('value'),
            $('div.answer_wrap input#2').attr('value'),
            $('div.answer_wrap input#3').attr('value'),
            $('div.answer_wrap input#4').attr('value'),
            $('div.answer_wrap input#5').attr('value')
        ]
    };
```

active_question is set to 'poll', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 depending on the question being worked on at the moment. I am trying to post this object to a php script using the following JS code.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:            '/somewebsite/poll/create?json=show',
        type:           'POST',
        // dataType:        'json',
        data:           poll_data,
        contentType:        'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success:        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

My PHP code is very simple.

```
    echo json_encode($_POST); exit;
```

When I run the script and click the button that triggers the submission of the data, I receive the alert (so the actual ajax code works), but the result from my PHP script is just an empty array. I think that this is an issue with the way the object is constructed, but I am not sure, and have not been able to find a work around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just to verify to everyone: the problem is not on the server. The server is not receiving the data, which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a few things:

poll_data is not a valid JSON object.  You would have to use poll_data[active_question], which IS a valid JSON object.  jQuery should serialize this correctly.  Remove the contentType -- I am pretty sure that is for php (not positive) but your code wouldn't work for me until I removed it.  Finally, the appending of json=show to the query string doesn't do anything..it will just be ignored.

A couple minor things too: you can use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`, and have you looked into `.serialize()` to create your post data for you?

Comment: Ok, your missing the point. Even if change my PHP code to. echo var_dump($_POST); There is no data, PHP is not receiving the JSON object.

Comment: Edited my answer -- hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, great that helped alot. I changed my javascript code to the following.

  $.ajax({
   url:   '/polple/poll/create',
   type:   'POST',
   dataType:  'json',
   data:   {'poll': poll_data['poll'], 'a': poll_data[0], 'b': poll_data[1]},
      success:  function(data) {
    alert(data);
      }
  });

Now everything seems to be working fine. Also thank you for the heads up on .val instead of .attr('value'), and the ?json=show is actually for my PHP code it tells the code to output json instead of HTML. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

do this on server

```
$data;
$data->question=$_POST['question']
$data->answer=$_POST['answers']
echo json_encode($data);
```

do this for **ajax request**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/somewebsite/poll/create?json=show',
        type:'POST',
        //modified data proprty
        data:poll_data[active_question],
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: problem with this is that no POST data is available on the server.

Comment: If a do a simple var_dump($_POST); on the server i get the following content.

array(0) {
}

Comment: Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/polple/poll/create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:text/html
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=94
Pragma:no-cache