# Google Maps Object to PHP thorough AJAX request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, mongodb

I'm trying to cache Google Maps geocoding results in my database (mongoDB).

So that users would not reach their 2500 daily geocoding quota.

What I'm trying to do is that when Geocoding response is OK then

cache it to my database by sending those response object and status object to my database

as it is by sending those two objects to PHP through AJAX.

and retrieve the stored data and use it just as the data from Google Maps Geocoding.

But I'm facing a problem that PHP does not recognize those objects and cannot put them in

mongoDB.

I have tried to accept those two objects by

```
$response = json_decode((object) $_POST['response']);
$status = json_decode((object) $_POST['status']);
```

but those two become 'null' did not help at all.

Should I make a new JSON which is comprised of all strings and numbers to send through AJAX?

Or is there a way to let PHP recognize JSON with JavaScript Object so that I can put that in MongoDB?

EDIT: I think I'm also facing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903401/cant-post-json-object-using-jquery-post) while trying to post those objects to php

Comment: @Kenaniah I forgot to put json_decode on getting those variables..

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['response'])` is the proper way to decode it.

Comment: @Kenaniah but PHP does not recognize Google Maps' objects through json_decode

Comment: I've had no problem json_decoding google maps objects before. var_dump() the variables you're trying to decode and post them to your question.

Comment: @Kenaniah Did you just do json_decode($_POST['response') or json_decode((object)$_POST['response'])?

Comment: The first one. Please `var_dump($_POST)` and add the results to your question.

Comment: @Kenaniah I have found that I cannot even send those two objects through $.post('/api/geocode', { results:results, status:status });
and it says "TypeError: a is undefined"...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6215/discussion-between-inspiredjw-and-kenaniah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has solved by using [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Simply I just send

```
$.post(url, { response:JSON.stringify(response), status:JSON.stringify(response) });
```

Let php to recognize those objects as string first and then

json_decode is able to convert those JSON strings to array in PHP.